# How can i open an existing model from external application

Tags: c#, .net, powerdesigner

I saw "Ole Automation" examples of creating Physical Database Model elements, but there is no examples of opening an existing DB model. 
Can someone please help me? My expectations are similar to this pseudo-code:

```
    PdCommon.Application pd;
    pd = PdCommon.OpenApplication(%Path%);
    ...
```

Comment: In scripting (VBScript), there's an `OpenModel` global function, which seems to be part of the `Application` interface. Maybe `PdCommon.Application.OpenModel`?

Comment: @pascal, you were right. It can be done by using OpenModel method of existing application.

`PdCommon.Application    pdApplication;`
`PdPDM.Model             pdModel;`
`pdApplication = new PdCommon.Application();`
`pdModel = (PdPDM.Model)pdApplication.OpenModel(@"C:\SVN\RAS_DB_Control\trunk\Northwind - MS\Model\Northwind.pdm");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202367/pascal) was right.

```
 PdCommon.Application    pdApplication;
 PdPDM.Model             pdModel;

 pdApplication = new PdCommon.Application();
 pdModel = (PdPDM.Model)pdApplication.OpenModel(@"C:\SVN\RAS_DB_Control\trunk\Northwind - MS\Model\Northwind.pdm");
```